# AngularJS dynamically specify flag on orderBy

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to perform an orderBy operation in AngularJS based on a chosen select box value.

The problem I'm having is changing the optional `:true` or `:false` flags depending on the selected value.

For example, 'alphabetical' order, the flag would have to be `:false`, but for 'date' (most recent), the flag needs to be `:true`.

I've tried hardcoding the flags in the scope options but still not working.

html

```
<div>
  <label>Country filter</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="countryFilter" />

  <label>Order by</label>
  <select ng-model="selectedOrder" ng-options="option for option in options"></select>
</div>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="detail in details | filter:{country: countryFilter} | orderBy:selectedOrder">{{ detail }}</li>    
</ul>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

  // order by options
  $scope.options = ['country', 'address', 'date'];

  // all countries
  $scope.details = [{
    id:1, country:'Finland', address:'Mainstreet 2', date:'2015-05-02'
  },{
    id:2, country:'Mexico', address:'Some address', date:'2015-05-05'
  },{
    id:3, country:'Canada', address:'Snowroad 45', date:'2015-03-02'
  }];
});
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WkeTtkjYfYZ5DhLIZEUd?p=preview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to change your order options from strings to objects, which include the information if the list should be reversed for this order:

```
$scope.options = [{value : 'country', reversed : false}, {value : 'address', reversed : false}, {value : 'date', reversed : true}];
```

And the ng-repeat to:

```
<li ng-repeat="detail in details | filter:{country: countryFilter} | orderBy:selectedOrder.value:selectedOrder.reversed">{{ detail }}</li>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/JXtHa2jXUy7Y5BsvsdL9?p=preview